# Duplicate answer to multiple unique questions should not be deleted, correct?

Tags: feature-request

First, this is not a Meta duplicate question, even though there is a similar seeming question already up here. It is different in that in my case there were two unique questions, not seemingly related to each other. In other words, there are actually three symptoms that have the same solution and if you are searching for one symptom, my post mentions the other symptoms as well, as knowing them may be useful for troubleshooting and qualifying the answer I have given.

josilber deleted my answer to [Add controller option is missing in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901637/add-controller-option-is-missing-in-visual-studio-2015/34912564)

The answer is identical to the question [Visual Studio 2015 Razor View MVC Types not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594763/visual-studio-2015-razor-view-mvc-types-not-recognized)

The answer to each is:

> From Chris Zhao on asp.net: You could consider uninstalling VS 2015, and reinstall it again,and check whether "Web Developer tools" is selected [go into Custom during the installation to be sure it is checked].
>
> I did this and is solved my Add Controller, Add View, ability to add an new project using the MVC template problems - and got rid of red underlines under Viewbag.

josilber posted this when deleting my answer:

> Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, tailor your answers to the question. – josilber♦ 4 hours ago

This is wrong and does not serve the people who are trying to resolve this issue. I had already looked for those two things and had them open when I found the answer elsewhere and posted it here. Why work against the benefit of people who use this site?

A feature request would be to allow people who know what they are doing to challenge unjustified deletes.

Comment: What exactly do you propose?

Comment: How does not voting to close as a duplicate 'serve the people who are trying to resolve this issue'? They'll see a duplicate answer has the solution, so they'll click through. Allowing duplicate answers merely encourages duplicate questions.

Comment: @Rob, it serves people who are trying to resolve the issue by giving them a solution that worked for me and has worked for others. If I had found the answer on SO, I wouldn't have posted it nor would I have had to look elsewhere. What does 'They'll see a duplicate answer has the solution, so they'll click through.' mean?

Comment: *"allow people who know what they are doing to challenge unjustified deletes"* - there are already ways of doing that, such as posting on Meta.

Comment: @vaultah, it would be nice to have a dispute option. No one who has a problem with a legitimate answer would be happy with the answer being deleted. This is counter to serving the users. I think I have wasted enough time on this.

Comment: @Reid I mean, when a question is closed as a duplicate, a big banner appears at the top appears saying "The answer is located here". Not only do duplicate targets help with SEO (and subsequently finding the right answer), it also serves to provide a *very good solution* (not always the case, of course), rather than bits and pieces of the solution all over the site.

Comment: @Rob, do you understand that the answer has been deleted? Not the question. The answer. Two unrelated questions can have the same answer and the same cause can produce multiple problems that are not obviously related.

Comment: @Reid Yes, I understand the answer was deleted. My whole point is (as well as the mod's - apparently), is that the answer did not need to exist, as the answer is found in another question. Subsequently, the question you answered should have been closed and pointed to the other question.

Comment: @Rob, You lose information by eliminating the question, because people are searching for a solution based on their framing of their problem. Just as josilber destroyed information of use by deleting a working answer which could have been tried by others.

Comment: Exactly duplicating answers is a bad idea for the same reasons we seek to have databases designed in 3NF. As it stands you've introduced an update anomaly - if someone now wanted to improve the formatting (e.g.  proper markup for the quotes) or content of your answer they have to magically guess that the same applies to your other identical answers.

Comment: [The FAQ about duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/253560) defines duplicates as two questions that have the same answers, so in general if you find yourself copying the same answer to multiple questions you should be closing them as duplicates instead. Closing as duplicate helps future visitors find their answers without us needing to have many copies of the same answer. If the two questions are not duplicates then they should have different answers, so tailor your answers accordingly (as I suggested in the comment I left you).

Comment: @josilber, I understand the general principle. However, some problems are specific and have different solutions. And solution A may work for some and solution B may work for others. As such, combining makes no sense. Problem X may have A and B and C as possible solutions. Problem Y may have C and F and H as possible solutions. In the immediate case, people may not know they have more than one of the problems as this is not a show stopper, merely something that is quite frustrating and a nuisance. I had looked it up for a few days on and off before finding the solution that worked for me.

Comment: @Reid if the questions are truly different you should be able to tailor your answers to the question; I've done my best with your two answers in this case (as a non-domain expert) and undeleted the answer in question. Please edit as necessary, and going forward please try to tailor your answers or vote to close as duplicate instead of posting duplicate answers.

Comment: @josilber, I am not going to touch your edits, but will point out that there is important information in the originals which could help people determine if the answer actually fits their case and this information is absent in the edited version. Peace.

Answer (score 5):

"Try reinstalling Visual Studio" is not a good answer, it is a last resort shotgun approach that only should be considered when everything else fails. You can also simply run setup again to add additional components.

More specifically, there are thousands of pages on www.asp.net, so in your answer you should link to where you found this advice.

No, the questions are not duplicates (they're about entirely different problems altogether), but the answer shouldn't be cross-posted in its current form either.

Comment: Everything else failed.  And it worked. And it worked for a reason and solved several problems at once. Also, I have seen the linking to other sites discouraged up here I believe.